# angularjs how to catch http response data that sent by browser

Tags: angularjs, http

As title, I want to catch Http response that sent by the browser.

Let say a redirect to "http://domain/api/something", actually, a GET request to "http://domain/api/something" which return a JSON data.
 How can I get that data on first load using AngularJs?

Comment: Please be more descriptive about what you're trying to accomplish, and also make some attempt at doing so.

Comment: Assume that user enter my page "http://domain/api/something" on browser then my server returns a JSON data/ a Html page or so. In case of a Html page, the browser will render it. The question is, how can I also get that Html page in text/HTML format without sending another request.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your code as below

```
app.service('feedbackService', function ($http) {
   this.getFeedbackPaged = function () {
      return $http.get('http://domain/api/something');
   };
});

app.controller('feedbackController', function ($scope, feedbackService, $filter) {
  // Constructor for this controller
  init();

  function init() {
      feedbackService.getFeedbackPaged().then(function(data){
          $scope.feedbackItems=data;
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: By this way, I'll send another request rather than catch a response that already sent by Browser, isn't it?

Comment: Please give more descriptive. once you load the init(); It will call the http GET  method and response will store in $scope.feedbackItems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use $http service as follows.

```
$http.get(
  'http://domain/api/something'
).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.data = JSON.parse(response.data);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // error handler
});
```

reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http